# Increasing performance of 100 images in one page without one-way binding

Tags: angularjs

I have a view which requires me to display around 100+ image thumbs. The code today is something like this:

```
 <figure ng-repeat="moment in moments | onlyEnabledMoments">
   <img image-spinner-src="{{constructFrame(moment)}}" 
        img-spinner-w="{{moment.Event.width}}" 
        img-spinner-h="{{moment.Event.height}}"
        image-spinner-loader="lines" on-tap="playEvent(moment)" />
 </figure>
```

Where `constructFrame(moment)` is:

```
$scope.constructFrame = function (moment) {
    var stream = "";
    stream = moment.Event.recordingURL + "/index.php?view=image" +
    "&eid=" + moment.Event.Id + "&fid=" +
    NVR.getSnapshotFrame() +
      "&width=" + moment.Event.thumbWidth * 2 +
      "&height=" + moment.Event.thumbHeight * 2;
    stream += NVR.getAuthToken();
    return stream;

  };
```

Note that the reason I call a function is that the function returns a token that changes over time.

The problem with this approach is that with around 100+ images, the performance is terrible on mobile devices. I understand this is probably due to constant expression evaluation. I can't use one-way binding here, because token may change.

How do I improve the performance?

Comment: Do you need to show all 100? In our application we paginate or load on scroll for pages with large amounts of records

Comment: Yes. This is a security system and folks often use large monitors and want as much as possible to fit a screen. Thanks.

Comment: But this wouldnt be the case for mobile devices? I would look at detecting if its a mobile device and having a different view for mobile devices if the performance is ok on desktop

Comment: So actually, this is also an electron app for desktops as well. Performance on both need improvement. I've actually made good progress with one time binding and ng-if to re-force evaluations. Using scalyr did not work (another SO thread) well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to post a follow up on how some simple changes made a big difference. My users are now reporting that scrolling and usage is very usable, both on mobile devices and desktops.

1. In general, one time binding, where possible makes a big difference. For example, looking at my code block above, I could add one time binding to the width and heigh parameters.
2. I got rid of the HTML template filter, (`onlyEnabledMoments`). I *could* have used the `$filter` service but really did not need to. I just populated the array without the elements that I did not need (the filter was just lazy coding on my part). I read filters are computed twice every digest cycle.
3. I found a way to work around the image url and `constructFrame` - if you recall, my issue was that the auth token changes once in a while. But really does not need to be recomputed at every digest. So I worked it around as such:

```
<span ng-if="!authRecomputingTrigger">
 <figure ng-repeat="moment in moments">
  <img image-spinner-src="::{{constructFrame(moment)}}" 
            img-spinner-w="::{{moment.Event.width}}" 
            img-spinner-h="::{{moment.Event.height}}"
            image-spinner-loader="lines" on-tap="playEvent(moment)" /> 
 </figure>
</span>
```

And in my code, when auth is recomputed, I do something like:

```
$scope.authRecomputingTrigger = true;
$timeout (function() {$scope.authRecomputingTrigger=false;},300);
```

This forces a UI refresh (300ms to be safe, I suppose even 10ms is fine as digest cycles are 10ms). It's an ugly hack, but the performance benefits were tremendous